# WooCommerce prevent execution of webhook for new orders which items in certain category

Tags: php, wordpress, woocommerce, webhooks, hook-woocommerce

Hi guys I've been puzzled by this issue for 2 days now and I cannot find a way to make it working. I have WooCommerce webhook triggered when new Order is created, but I want to prevent execution for orders which items are in certain categories. I'm trying to achieve this by using the [woocommerce_webhook_should_deliver](https://woocommerce.wp-a2z.org/oik_hook/woocommerce_webhook_should_deliver/) filter-hook. Here is my attempt and I'll explain the issue with it:

```
function custom_woocommerce_webhook_should_deliver($shouldDeliver, $instance, $arg) {
    $excludeCategories = [16, 17];
    $order = wc_get_order($arg);
    $logger = wc_get_logger();

    foreach ($order->get_items() as $item_id => $item) {
        $term_ids = wp_get_post_terms(
            $item->get_product_id(), 'product_cat', array('fields' => 'ids')
        );
        $result = array_diff($excludeCategories, $term_ids);

        $logger->add(
            sprintf(
                "send-order-debug-%s",
                (int)$arg
            ), json_encode(['res' => $result, 'ids' => $term_ids])
        );
        if (count($excludeCategories) !== count($result)) {
            $shouldDeliver = false;
            break;
        }
    }

    $logger->add(
        sprintf(
            "send-order-debug-%s",
            (int)$arg
        ),
        json_encode(
            [
                'shouldDeliver' => (int)$shouldDeliver,
                'itemsCount' => count($order->get_items()),
            ]
        )
    );

    return $shouldDeliver;
}

add_filter('woocommerce_webhook_should_deliver', 'custom_woocommerce_webhook_should_deliver', 10, 3);
```

As you can see what I'm doing is to get the order and try to prevent the webhook execution if there are items in 2 categories(hardcoded in the example). The problem and for my big surprise is that in the moment of this check **$order->get_items()** returns empty array, thus my filter always returns true. Here is the log I've put at the end of the method.

```
{"shouldDeliver":1,"itemsCount":0}
```

The interesting thing here to know is that there is nothing wrong with the order content, it's not empty and when webhook is executed I receive the order with it's items.

I'm not a WooCommerce/WordPress guru and I don't know what is the way of saving orders and the order items, but I assume that in the moment I get in this filter, order items are still not created. Anyone can give me some ideas of how to make this working? I'm open to totally different approach of solving this task(please without worthless assumptions, only tested and working examples). Thanks in advance!

Answer (score 0):

After posting this issue to the official WooCommerce support page and getting no answer I took a slightly different approach and instead of working with the order I've simply taken the cart items instead. This of course doesn't answer the question, why in the moment we get in this filter-hook, **$order->get_items()** returns empty array, but it solves the task. So here is the workaround for anyone who needs it.

```
function custom_woocommerce_webhook_should_deliver($shouldDeliver, $instance, $arg) {
    global $woocommerce;
    $items = $woocommerce->cart->get_cart(); // we get current cart
    $excludeCategories = [16, 17];

    foreach ($items as $item_id => $item) {
        $term_ids = wp_get_post_terms(
            $item['product_id'], 'product_cat', array('fields' => 'ids')
        );
        $result = array_diff($excludeCategories, $term_ids);
        
        if (count($excludeCategories) !== count($result)) {
            $shouldDeliver = false;
            break;
        }
    }

    return $shouldDeliver;
}

add_filter('woocommerce_webhook_should_deliver', 'custom_woocommerce_webhook_should_deliver', 10, 3);
```